# Unable read MSWord file in iOS Phonegap APP

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an iOS hybrid app, developed using, Phonegap 2.1.0.

I want to display MSWord file using InAppBrowser plugin. Word file is located on the server.

I tried for pdf, it worked, but not working for MS word (.doc) file. It gives message `Unable to Read Document.`
If I tried to open the word file is safari, it shows the same message.

I also tried `openWith` plugIn from github, but no luck.
Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using google web embedded view for opening the doc file.
`http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="Your link to doc file"` as your word file is on server so just pass the link in above code.

Comment: I opened the above link using InAppBrowser, and mentioned my server file path in the url parameter. But no luck. I got following message:
"Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time. Please try again later.You can also try to download the original document by clicking here." 
And after clicking on the link, I got the same message as earlier I used to get:
"Unable to Read Document."
Any thing which I am missing?

Comment: link should have .docx at the end. i also faced same error previously but solved when i changed .doc to .docx . try it hope it helps.